# How to view information about a newly loaded external Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a simple Hello World kernel module from http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x121.html
I added a few lines with `MODULE_AUTHOR`, and `MODULE_DESCRIPTION`

It builds successfully, I'm able to insert it with `insmod` into the current kernel, view logs with `dmesg`, check that the module exists with `lsmod`.

However, I want to be able to view the module's info with `modinfo` but it doesn't work.
I get `modinfo: ERROR: Module hello not found.`
I tried running `depmod` and `depmod -A` but they didn't make a difference.

Is there any way to make `modinfo` "reload" so that I can view info for newly added modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page:

> modinfo extracts information from the Linux Kernel modules given on the command line. If the module name is not a filename, then the /lib/modules/version directory is searched, as is also done by
>          modprobe(8) when loading kernel modules.

So it looks like this command just uses the kernel module files to get this information, so you can either run:

```
modinfo hello.ko
```

or you could put your kernel module in the `/lib/modules/version/` directory

Comment: To get info on kernel modules that are presently loaded up into the kernel, one can exploit sysfs:

# ls -a /sys/module/<name-of-kernel-module>